# how can I access to graylog main page when deployed with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, graylog

I'm building a .net core application, and I want to use [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) for logging. In Visual Studio I've updated the `docker-compose.yml` in order to include also graylog container, inspiring by what I can see in [this github page](https://github.com/Graylog2/docker-compose/blob/main/open-core/docker-compose.yml).

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myproject.frontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myprojectfrontend
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Servers/myproject.Frontend/Dockerfile

  identity.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityapi
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Services/Identity.API/Dockerfile

  # Install the mongodb for offline data storage
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: "on-failure"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - "mongodb_data:/mnt/host/e/docker/mongodb/db/" # Check the wsl docker desktop for folder

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:root@mongo:27017/

  # Install graylog, centralized logger server: https://github.com/Graylog2/docker-compose/blob/main/open-core/docker-compose.yml
  opensearch:
    image: "opensearchproject/opensearch:2.4.0"
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "action.auto_create_index=false"
      - "plugins.security.ssl.http.enabled=false"
      - "plugins.security.disabled=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        hard: -1
        soft: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - "os_data:/mnt/host/e/docker/opensearch/data"
    restart: "on-failure"

  graylog:
    hostname: "server"
    image: "${GRAYLOG_IMAGE:-graylog/graylog:5.0}"
    depends_on:
      opensearch:
        condition: "service_started"
      mongo:
        condition: "service_started"
    entrypoint: "/usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it opensearch:9200 --  /docker-entrypoint.sh"
    environment:
      GRAYLOG_NODE_ID_FILE: "/usr/share/graylog/data/config/node-id"
      GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET: "passwordpassword"
      GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2: "2e2b24f8ee40bb847fe85bb23336a39ef5948e6b49d897419ced68766b16967a"
      GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:9000"
      GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI: "http://localhost:9000/"
      GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "http://opensearch:9200"
      GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI: "mongodb://mongodb:27017/graylog"
    ports:
      - "5044:5044/tcp"   # Beats
      - "5140:5140/udp"   # Syslog
      - "5140:5140/tcp"   # Syslog
      - "5555:5555/tcp"   # RAW TCP
      - "5555:5555/udp"   # RAW TCP
      - "9000:9000/tcp"   # Server API
      - "12201:12201/tcp" # GELF TCP
      - "12201:12201/udp" # GELF UDP
      #- "10000:10000/tcp" # Custom TCP port
      #- "10000:10000/udp" # Custom UDP port
      - "13301:13301/tcp" # Forwarder data
      - "13302:13302/tcp" # Forwarder config
    volumes:
      - "graylog_data:/mnt/host/e/docker/graylog/data/data"
      - "graylog_journal:/mnt/host/e/docker/graylog/data/journal"
    restart: "on-failure"

volumes:
  mongo:
  mongodb_data:
  os_data:
  graylog_data:
  graylog_journal:
```

When I debug the `docker-compose` project in Visual Studio, I can see that it works; the browser is opened, I can see the main page of my project. I'm also able to go to the `mongo-express` main page if I paste this address to my browser: `http://localhost:8081/`.

But I've two main problems:

- I'm not able to access to graylog main page in any way. Even if its container is running, I cannot find the right address to paste in my browser in order to see its main page. I've tried following addresses:

```
http://localhost:9000
https://localhost:9000
```

Also, I I've a connection error to mongodb. If I go to the containers window of Visual Studio, I can see those messages in the log of the graylog container:

```
2023-05-29 19:52:28,831 INFO : org.graylog2.bootstrap.preflight.MongoDBPreflightCheck - MongoDB is not available. Retry #1
2023-05-29 19:52:30,831 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2023-05-29 19:53:00,831 INFO : org.graylog2.bootstrap.preflight.MongoDBPreflightCheck - MongoDB is not available. Retry #2
2023-05-29 19:53:02,832 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2023-05-29 19:53:32,832 INFO : org.graylog2.bootstrap.preflight.MongoDBPreflightCheck - MongoDB is not available. Retry #3
2023-05-29 19:53:34,833 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2023-05-29 19:54:04,833 INFO : org.graylog2.bootstrap.preflight.MongoDBPreflightCheck - MongoDB is not available. Retry #4
2023-05-29 19:54:06,833 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

So I assume that there's some error in the initialization of mongodb, but I don't know what.

- I don't see any content in mapped folders. I've created directories manually before starting everything, but all of them are always empty. I don't know if it's right or not; but even if I can understand that graylog are empty because of some problem, also mongodb folders are empty, even if I can open mongo-express by using the address localhost:8081 and I create a `graylog` collection.

So my question is: what I'm doing wrong? How can I fix my `docker-compose` in order to see the graylog home page? What should I do in order to let him to communicate with mongo?